# Socket API on top of SCSI?

Tags: sockets, protocols, network-protocols, tcp, scsi

Is there any existing software available that does the usual socket API over different transports? I am particularly interested in SCSI now, but knowing if there is something available for other transports would be great as well. It would need something on both sides of the connection, in the case of SCSI, an emulation layer using SCSI underneath and some target side software as well.

As to why I need this, I need to support an existing application that uses sockets to work over FC, and SCSI would fit well in that respect. IP over FC is long dead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The RFC has number [2143](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2143).

[Here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2344) is an article in the Linux Journal about it, by the author of [RFC 2143](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2143), Ben Elliston.

It describes not a separate socket API on top of SCSI, (like for instance UNIX sockets are separate from TCP/IP sockets) instead it's about implementing TCP/IP over SCSI.

Back in 2001, this was [implemented for Linux](http://ipoverscsi.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I did see this, I was hoping there is something available that already does the mapping and is implemented and tested. Is there something like that already available?

Comment: @MarkLobo, there is, but it's more than 10 years old now. Either dig up old Debian/Redhat ISOs from that time period, or port the code to new kernels...